# Custom C++ STL-like doubly linked-list(C++11)

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++11, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

This is the link list I just created. It works fine for now, but would want to know if I could make it better.

## list.hpp

```
/******************************************************************************************************
 * Purpose: Custom Doubly Linked-list.
 *
 * Author: Sahil Arora
 *
 * Version : 1.0
 *
 * Date of Creation : 06/04/2016
 *
 * Usage: Include "list.hpp" and create objects.
 *
 * Bugs : None
******************************************************************************************************/
#ifndef LIST_HPP_
#define LIST_HPP_

namespace mod
{
    template<typename T>
    struct link{
            T value;
            link<T>* prev;
            link<T>* next;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class list
    {
        int len;
        link<T> *head, *tail;
        public:
            list() {head = tail = nullptr; len = 0;}    //default constructor
            list(list<T>& x);                           //copy constructor
            ~list();                                    //destructor
            void append(const T& value);                //appending an element
            void append(list<T>& x);                    //appending a list
            int length() {return len;}                  //returning length of the list
            bool empty() {return len<=0;}               //check if empty
            void cons(const T& value);                  //adding an element to the head
            void remove(const T& x);                    //remove the first occurence of an element
            link<T>* get_head() { return head; }        //return head pointer
            link<T>* get_tail() { return tail; }        //return tail pointer
            class iterator{                             //iterator class
                link<T> *ptr;
                public:
                    iterator() {ptr = nullptr;}         
                    iterator(link<T>* p) {ptr = p;}
                    link<T>* get_ptr(){return ptr;}
                    T& operator*(){return ptr->value;}
                    void operator=(iterator iter){ptr = iter.get_ptr();}
                    bool operator==(iterator iter){return ptr == iter.get_ptr();}
                    void operator++() { if(ptr!=nullptr) ptr = ptr->next; }
                    void operator--(){ if(ptr!=nullptr) ptr = ptr->prev;}
                    bool operator!=(iterator iter){return ptr != iter.get_ptr();}  
            };
            iterator begin() {return iterator(head);}   //begin iterator
            iterator end() {return iterator(nullptr);}  //end iterator
    };

    template<typename T>
    list<T>::list(list<T>& x){
        link<T>* ptr = x.get_head();
        if(x.length()==0){
            head = tail = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        link<T>* ptr2 = new link<T>;
        ptr2->value = ptr->value;
        ptr2->prev = ptr2->next = nullptr;
        head = ptr2; 
        ptr = ptr->next;
        while(ptr!=nullptr){
            link<T>* temp = new link<T>;
            temp->value = ptr->value;
            temp->next = nullptr;
            temp->prev = ptr2;
            ptr2->next = temp;
            ptr2 = temp;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        tail = ptr2;
        len = x.length();
    }

    template<typename T>
    list<T>::~list(){
        link<T> *ptr = head; 
        while(ptr != nullptr){
            link<T>* ptr2 = ptr->next;
            delete ptr;
            ptr = ptr2;
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void list<T>::append(const T& a){
        link<T> *ptr = new link<T>;
        ptr->value = a;
        ptr->next = nullptr;
        ptr->prev = tail;
        if(len==0){
            head = tail = ptr;
            ++len;
            return;
        }
        tail->next = ptr;
        tail = ptr;
        ++len;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void list<T>::cons(const T& a){
        link<T> *ptr = new link<T>;
        ptr->value = a;
        ptr->next = head;
        ptr->prev = nullptr;
        head->prev = ptr;
        head = ptr;
        ++len;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void list<T>::remove(const T& a){
        link<T> *ptr = head;
        if(len>0 && head->value == a){
            head = head->next;
            if(len>1)
                head->prev = nullptr;
            delete ptr;
            --len;
            return;
        }
        while(ptr!=nullptr){
            if(ptr->value == a){
                ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
                if(ptr==tail)
                    tail = ptr->prev;
                else
                    ptr->next->prev = ptr->prev;
                delete ptr;
                --len;
                return;
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void list<T>::append(list<T>& x){
        for(list<T>::iterator it = x.begin() ; it!=x.end(); ++it)
        append(*it);
    }

}

#endif
```

## tester.cpp

Tester program:

```
#include "list.hpp"
#include <iostream>

 using namespace mod;
 using std::cout;
 using std::cin;
 template<typename T>
 void print(list<T>& l){
    cout<<"List Length: "<<l.length()<<"\nList: ";
    for(list<int>::iterator it = l.begin() ; it!=l.end(); ++it)
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
 }
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    list<int> l1;
    print(l1);
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        l1.append(i*10);
    print(l1);
    list<int> l2;
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        l2.append(i*15);
    print(l2);
    l2.append(l1);
    print(l2);
    list<int> l3(l2);
    print(l3);
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        l3.append(i*3);
    print(l3);
    l3.append(l1);
    l3.remove(10);
    l3.remove(20);
    l3.remove(30);
    l3.remove(40);
    l3.cons(-155);
    print(l3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `append(&list)` is broken; it'll double free the nodes that were in the passed in list. So either duplicate the list or clear the passed in one (and change the name)

Comment: Yeah! This was a great advice. I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code readabilty: if you decide to implement the member functions outside the class definition, do that for all of them. Including constructors and destructor.

Use c++ syntax to initialize your data members before the constructor body for example:

```
list () : len(0), head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
```

Don't create constructors (especially copy-constructors) if you don't **absolutely ** have to, use default ones when you can.

For example: your iterator class.

A good rule of thumb is:
If you feel you must explicitly declare  one of the three:

- copy constructor
- assignment
- destructor

You must declare them all.

Last but defently not least: use const wherever you can.

This will make your list less type error prone and will allow it's user to do less stupid stuff with it.

Comment: How do I use `const` in a class? And for what should I use `const` here? Also, does the c++ syntax make any performance changes?

Comment: Const in a functions definition is like a "contract" between the writer of the function to the user. As the writer if you add for instance: f (const int&) it means you guarantee that you won't change the value of the int parameter. There are a lot more ways to use const. I suggest you try to explore yourself. About the syntax, if a class has a private data member it creates an instance of it before you enter the constructor body. Which means that there is a moment where your data members exist but not initialized. It is considered good practice.